# urlLoader open URL fails in EXE Flash, using browser it works

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

It rarely happened, I use a flash in exe type to access url in local server. It usually success to access the url. When it fail to access the url, open the ie to access the browser. the url works. After using browser, flash success to access the url. The url would return the JSON content. I use URLLoader to load url, and the return error is no responding when it happen.

If the error happen, it would not access the url even restart the computer.

Did anyone ever solve this issue? Please help.

Comment: Can you provide some code? It would help to find out where the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is the url that you enter into your URLLoader. The difference between URL's can be:

url:\ \next\ \last (next to eachother)

or

url:\next\last

or

url:/next/last

I had this problem a few times while referring to a folder on a mobile device. You can try it, maybe it is the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it always access the same url, such as http://localhost:8080/.. we set up a server in the same machine, and use flash to access it. It always works, the application works normally for 4 month. But it fail to work yesterday, and it's fixed by using browser to access the url.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into a security issue.  SWFs are by default set to access the 'local sandbox' only. This means that when running a SWF locally in the standalone player, you will be unable to access any "remote" content, meaning content coming from a web server (even localhost).

Two options to allow your SWF to access web data:
1) Place the SWF on a web server (localhost will work) and open it through a browser
2) Change the security setting to allow 'network only' access instead of local.  In the Flash IDE this can be done by editing your Publish Settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this case, we use "exe" type to accss the url. And it always works. The application works normally for 4 month. But it fail to work 4/21, and it's fixed by using browser to access the url.